# Using the less than comparison operator for strings

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, string-comparison, stdstring

I'm following a tutorial for C++ and looking at strings and overloading with operators such as `+=`, `==`, `!=` etc. Currently I have a simple if-statement:

```
if(s1 < s2)
    cout << s2 <<endl;
else
  if(s2 < s1)
    cout << s1 << endl;
  else
    cout << "Equal\n";
```

But how does this work, and how does the program decide which string is greater than another?
looking around I've found a basic template declaration:

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator< ( const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& lhs,
                 const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs );
```

Does this define how `<` works? If so, what does `<charT,traits,Allocator>` mean / do?

Also do the following operators have any meaning for strings? `-=` and `*=`

Comment: Since `std::string` is actually a `typedef` for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`, one particular instantiation of that function template is `bool std::operator<(const std::string&, const std::string&);`, which is presumably called by your `s1 < s2` and `s2 < s1` expressions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The less-than operator on strings does a lexicographical comparison on the strings.  This compares strings in the same way that they would be listed in dictionary order, generalized to work for strings with non-letter characters.

For example:

```
"a" < "b"
"a" < "ab"
"A" < "a"             (Since A has ASCII value 65; a has a higher ASCII value)
"cat" < "caterpillar"
```

For more information, look at the **[`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)** algorithm, which the less-than operator usually invokes.

As for `-=` and `*=`, neither of these operators are defined on strings.  The only "arithmetic" operators defined are `+` and `+=`, which perform string concatenation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `"A" < "a"` is an ASCII assumption and doesn't work for other character sets, like [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). :-)

Comment: Also there's probably a general warning due: Lexicographical sorting is generally a bad idea if used in the UI. Not only are the results dependent on the actual encoding (and generally confusing), it's basically completely wrong for unicode.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the answers, knew there had to be a simple explanation!

Comment: String comparisons almost certainly does not invoke `lexicographical_compare`, though the algorithm used might be similar.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison operators implement [lexicographic ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of strings.

`-=` and `*=` are not defined for strings.