# "String Iterators Incompatible" error message when running bubble sort program

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector, bubble-sort

I am a beginner trying to bubble sort a vector of objects in C++. My goal is to sort the vector by member variables of each object element's member variable. So in the end, I would like the attributes off all the vector elements to be the same, just sorted in a different order. When I run the program, I get the following message:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    void sortInventory(vector<Vehicle> &carList)
    {
    bool swap;      
    Vehicle temp;  

    do
    {
        swap = false;

        for (int count = 0; count < carList.size(); count++)
        {

            transform(carList[count].getVIN().begin(), carList[count].getVIN().end(), carList[count].getVIN().begin(), ::tolower);

            if (carList[count].getVIN() > carList[count + 1].getVIN())
            {
                temp = carList[count];                          
                carList[count] = carList[count + 1];
                carList[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;    
            }
        }

    } while (swap);
}
```

Here is my class declaration:

```
class Vehicle
{
private:
    string VIN;

public:
    string getVIN();
    void   setVIN(string);

};
```

Here is my class implementation:

```
string Vehicle::getVIN()
{   return VIN;     }

void Vehicle::setVIN(string input)
{   VIN = input;    }
```

By the way, I am aware that I am not using efficient methods, but I am just starting to learn the language and I am learning to write the code.

I asked a question similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907135/how-to-sort-vector-of-objects-by-a-private-string-variable-alphabetically). However, none of the answers got me to where I wanted to go, although I feel like I am going in the right direction.

Comment: Where is the assertion fired? Could you show which line in your code the assertion fires on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jxh says, your transform line fails because you are making iterators to separate string objects. Why not try making the transform a separate routine?
If you want to be fancy you can define it inside the sort routine as a lambda function. Or you can just make it a separate routine defined separately.

```
// returns a lower case version of the string
std::string lower_case(std::string VIN_number){

  auto begin = std::begin(VIN_number);
  auto end = std::end(VIN_number);

  // Your code acting on one fixed string
  std::transform(begin, end, begin, ::tolower);

  return VIN_number; 
 }
```

Then when you do your comparison, do something like

```
if ( lower_case(carList[count].getVIN()) > lower_case(carList[count + 1]).getVIN()) )
```

Comment: This looks like it should work! However, I keep getting this error that says "Vector subscript out of range". Am I supposed to put `push_back` or something similar inside the if statement?

Comment: You are looping with count from 0 to `size() - 1`. But in your body, you are using the index `count + 1`. So at the last iteration of your loop you get an out of range error.

Answer (score 4):

This line of code attempts to convert the string for the VIN into lowercase text, but fails:

```
        transform(carList[count].getVIN().begin(),
                  carList[count].getVIN().end(),
                  carList[count].getVIN().begin(),
                  ::tolower);
```

Each call to `getVIN()` results in a separate `string` instance. Since the iterators are not from the same `string` instance, the failure is the result.

You don't show how you populate your `carList`, but one possible way to fix this is to save the `VIN` in lowercase at the time you save the VIN in the `carList`.