# Weird behaviour in string comparison C++

Tags: c++, string

I am using standard std::string variables which I try to compare. Quite strangely however, I am getting weird results:

```
string str1 = "44", str2 = "111";
bool smaller1 = str1.compare(str2) > 0;   // <- returns true, although should be false

bool smaller2 = "44" < "111";  // <- returns true, CORRECT

string str3(2, '4'), str4(3, '1');
bool small3 = str3 < str4;     // <- returns false, although should be true
```

I would expect since one string is shorter than the other, the lexacographical ordering should always give me true for "44" < "111".

The whole code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string str1 = "44", str2 = "111";
    string str3(2, '4'), str4(3, '1');

    bool cmp1 = str1 < str2,
         cmp2 = "44" < "111",
         cmp3 = str3 < str4,
         cmp4 = str3.compare(str4) < 0;

    std::cout << "1: " << cmp1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "2: " << cmp2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "3: " << cmp3 << "\n";
    std::cout << "4: " << cmp4 << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

and returns:

```
1: 0
2: 1
3: 0
4: 0
```

I am using g++ (GCC) 8.2.0 from MinGW 16.1 on Windows10. Am I missing something here? How can I force it to give me the correct results (shorter strings are smaller than longer).
Thanks.

Comment: *"lexacographical ordering should always give me true for `"44"` < `"111"`"* Why should it? Since the first char of `"111"` is less than the first char of `"44"`, `"111"` is lexacographically less than `"44"`. Next, in `"44" < "111"` you compare pointers rather than strings. Since the pointers point to different unrelated obejcts that gives you undefined behavior.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That should be an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: Look in a dictionary. Does ”zoo” come before ”aardvark” or after?

Comment: `"44" < "111"` is undefined behavior. You're likely comparing address values of string literals.

Comment: Hm. But don't we first compare the length of the strings? See e.g.:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparing-string-objects-using-relational-operators-c/

Comment: @pisoir geeksforgeeks is not a good source for facts.

Comment: If that page is typical of GeeksForGeeks, I would stop going to that website.

Comment: @selbie. True. This is random result.

Comment: @Eljay. Ok. But what about stackoverflow?;): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829434/using-the-less-than-comparison-operator-for-strings

One of the examples in the answer is: "cat" < "caterpillar"

EDIT: Aaa..because it starts with the same letter?

Comment: Because it does a character-by-character comparison, and the first non-matching character (or when one runs out of letters) determines the order for `string`.  But not for string literals, that just does a pointer comparison.

Comment: From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare): _A character sequence consisting of count1 characters starting at data1 is compared to a character sequence consisting of count2 characters starting at data2 as follows. First, calculate the number of characters to compare, as if by size_type rlen = std::min(count1, count2). Then compare the sequences by calling Traits::compare(data1, data2, rlen). For standard strings this function performs character-by-character lexicographical comparison._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool smaller2 = "44" < "111";  // <- returns true, CORRECT
```

No. You're just getting lukcy.  That's comparing the addresses of string literals, not the same thing as an instance of an std::string.   As a matter of fact, you could replace that expression in your code as "111" < "44" and it will likely return true if the compiler aligns the strings in memory in the same order as declared.

Correct way to compare strings lexicographical:

```
std::string str1 = "44";
std::string str2 = "111";
bool cmp1 = (str1 < str2);  // false, since '4' is greater than '1'
```

Correct way to compare strings as integers:

```
int val1 = std::stoi(str1);  // 44
int val2 = std::stoi(str2);  // 111
bool cmp2 = (val1 < val2);   // true since 44 is less than 111
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with the stoi() is that I am comparing huge integers (that's why I have them as strings). If there is no simple way with strings, I will probably have to switch to some library for arbitrary length integers.

Comment: @pisoir Compare the lengths first, then use `<` if they’re equal.

Comment: but you will have problems with negative numbers

Comment: I don't care about negative numbers. @selbie, yes, I realized that as well. Thanks again.