# What is the meaning of comparing strings with >=

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, string-comparison, stdstring

I am studying C++. I am surprised that it can compare strings. The following code compiles and runs successfully for strings `a` and `b`.

```cpp
if (b >= a)
{}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: The posted code does not compile:  `temp.cpp:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id`

Comment: Your surprise is surprising, presumably you've heard of alphabetic order, or dictionary order?

Comment: @john I tested using b="Bb" and a="Aa" and many others before asking the question, and got that it's true that b>a. I thought of that but I am not certain. I wanted to know how exactly they order string rather than just knowing by doing trial and error.

Comment: One more thing - often forgotten - the result of the compare is implementation defined. For example, a system with ASCII encoding will put upper case letters first, EBCDIC puts lower case letters first. Despite functions like `tolower` and `toupper` existing, there's still no case-instentive-compare function built into standard C++. <Rant>(But we get absolutely vital things in C++20 like a new formatting library ;-) )</Rant>

Comment: @Adola Sorry I thought you were surprised that there is any comparison possible at all. As Bathsheba says there is no standard order. It would be a crazy system where "a" > "b" but such a system is allowed. The commonest order is that defined by the [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All comparisons of `std::string` are lexicographical. See [`std::basic_string::operator>=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

You can find an excellent answer which explains this in detail here:
[Using the less than comparison operator for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13829456/5740428). The operators `<` and `>=` are not equivalent, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Probably a good idea to add the general link as well [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)